# If radio button in div is clicked then corresponding radio button in other div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone help me with a better way to write this?
So we are going to be adding to the list of levels and thumbnails and I would like this to work dynamically. So say if you selected level 15 then level 15 in the all-thumbnails div would be selected. Currently I have a script that is limited and would have to be repeated for the number of levels/thumbnails we create.

```js
$( "#all-levels input:eq(0)" ).click(function() {
  $( "#all-thumbnails input:eq(0)" ).click();
});
$( "#all-levels input:eq(1)" ).click(function() {
  $( "#all-thumbnails input:eq(1)" ).click();
});
```

```css
input {float: left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="all-levels">
  <div class="level">
    <div class="level-container">
      <input name="level-expand" id="level-expand587" value="3587"  type="radio">
    </div>
    <label for="level-expand3587" onclick="">
      <div class="level-amount-container">
        $18.00
      </div>
      <div class="level-label-container">
        Chai
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
<div class="level">
  <div class="level-container">
    <input name="level-expand" id="level-expand3589" value="3589"  type="radio">
    </div>
    <label for="level-expand3589" onclick="">
      <div class="level-amount-container">
        $25.00
      </div>
      <div class="level-label-container">
        Classic Frame
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="all-thumbnails">
  <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <label class="thumbnail-label" for="layout_id_1201">
      <img src="http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/thumbnail.gif" alt="Chai" border="0">
    </label>
    <input name="layout_id" id="layout_id_1201" value="1201"  type="radio">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <label class="thumbnail-label" for="layout_id_2456">
      <img src="https://mediaarchive.cern.ch/MediaArchive/Video/Public/Movies/CERN/2013/CERN-MOVIE-2013-051/CERN-MOVIE-2013-051-010/CERN-MOVIE-2013-051-010-thumbnail-135x101-at-5-percent.jpg" alt="Chai" border="0">
    </label>
    <input name="layout_id" id="layout_id_2456" value="2456"  type="radio">
  </div>
</div>
```

The current script clicks the corresponding radio button in the all-thumbnails div. Is there a way to do this without writing eq:(0), eq:(1), eq:(2) and so on so that no matter how many levels and thumbnails are added it will work dynamically?

**side note**: the thumbnails section will be hidden from front end users, in case that is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could find position index of element which was clicked, and then just query input element from another `div` with the index you just got. So if you click on third element in `#all-levels` `div`, then third element in `#all-thumbnails` will get click as well.

```
$( "#all-levels input" ).on('click', function(){
    var index = $( "#all-levels input" ).index(this);
    $( "#all-thumbnails input").eq(index).click();
})
```